# Firebase DB program works when logged in but not on boot using raspberry pi

Tags: bash, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, raspbian, boot

I am creating an IOT device with raspberry pi and using firebase admin sdk to communicate over the web. The code works exavtly how I want it to... Until I try adding it into local.rc for using it headlessly.

I'm unable to copy the error as it is only being thrown on boot. Here is a picture.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zzhouEyyN_RmttYVVOZXE0d2JXNWtTZHBjTlZYRTZkdy1N

From what I can read it has to do with an authority problem from where the program is being run. This is my rc.local:

```
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

#My line

sudo sh /home/pi/superscript.sh

exit 0
```

the supercript is

```
sudo python home/pi/servo.py & sudo python home/pi/buttonCheck.py&
```

I've tried with and without sudo.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. I suggest you add systemd service file with `Restart=Always` with your service. 2. Can you add `sleep 20` to the beginning of rc.local and restart? Why is there no `My IP address ...` line in the output?

Comment: I changed over to the systemd method  with services and now works, Thank you. The My IP adress does show up, it just isn't in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my process from running in rc.local to being a service in systemd, thanks to Kamil Cuk. [Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) is a link to the documentation for using systemd service method.
Though I am not experiencing any crashing, but putting Restart=Always will restart it after crash if applicable.

This is what it looks like.

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Room controller
 After=multi-user.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/servoController.py & /usr/bin/python /home/pi/buttonListener.py
 Restart=always

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```